# Windows 8 VPN Client connecting to UbuntuVNP Server fine but http from client is not working

Tags: server, windows-7, windows-8, vpn, pptp

I have connected my Windows Client to Ubuntu VPN pptp. I am able to access all servers in the private VPN network from my Windows client,  however when accessing the Internet from Windows client it resolves internet  but unable to connect to any site. The browser shows.. *Waiting for the site i.e google to reply*. The Ubuntu server is able to connect to Internet by Itself.

My configurations:

`netstat -rn`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.31.16.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
172.31.16.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.0.234   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ppp0
root@ip-172-31-21-21:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:14:08:6a:51:39
          inet addr:172.31.21.21  Bcast:172.31.31.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1618 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1497 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:327465 (327.4 KB)  TX bytes:346070 (346.0 KB)
          Interrupt:25

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
          inet addr:192.168.0.1  P-t-P:192.168.0.234  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1396  Metric:1
          RX packets:306 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:401 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3
          RX bytes:26719 (26.7 KB)  TX bytes:212361 (212.3 KB)
```

`iptables -L -n -v`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1125 packets, 103K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 662 packets, 239K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   38  1976 TCPMSS     tcp  --  ppp+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcpflags: 0x17/0x02 TCPMSS set 1356

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1114 packets, 296K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check you windows configuration.  You mos likely are using the remote gateway, you do not want to have that checked.  You want to only use the VPN tunnel when you are accessing IP's on the remote network.